# Download file to downloads folder ios/android using phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I am getting a JSON response from a web service that returns a file in  either binary or base64 . I want to save this file to the fileSystem.

1. I wanted to know the ideal (default/industry standard ) location to download these files for IOS/ ANdroid on the file system.
2. IF there is no ideal place i would want to save them in the default downloads folder for IOS/Android. I would then like to know what is the location of these folders.

I also wanted to know which methods in the Phonegap FileAPi i need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default place for downloads

Look the phonegap's [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) for more info.

With phonegap you can request de temporary or the permanent file system

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

on iOS PERSISTENT returns the Documents directory, and the TEMPORARY returns the Caches directory
on Android PERSISTENT returns the root of the SD card or phone memory, and TEMPORARY returns a folder inside the data folder.

To download the files use the [FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)