# Ionic 2 - How to setup file download?

Tags: ionic2

**THE SITUATION:**

In my Ionic 2 app I have a *Documents* section where the user should be able to download files.

I am trying to setup the [file transfer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/transfer/) for Ionic 2.

**THE CODE:**

**The documents component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Transfer } from 'ionic-native';

declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-documents',
  templateUrl: 'documents.html'
})

export class DocumentsPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {

    }

    downloadFile()
    {
        const fileTransfer = new Transfer();
        let url = 'http://MY_URL.com/example.txt';

        fileTransfer.download(url, cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'example.txt').then((entry) => 
        {
            console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        }, (error) => {
            // handle error
        });
    }
}
```

**THE RESULTS:**

**In the browser:**

I get the following error message: `FileTransfer is not defined` but probably because cordova doesn't work in the browser.

[image: FileTransfer is not defined]

**In the emulator:**

In the emulator the download seems actually successfull. In the console I can see: `donwload complete`.  but I didn't see starting any download and there is no trace of the downloaded file.

[image: donwload complete]

**In the device:**

In the device - after clicking for the download - nothing happens.. I don't see starting any download. In the file manager I don't see the file.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I properly setup the file download for Ionic 2?

There is something wrong in the code?

Should I see the download starting in the device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing seems to be wrong with the code.
According to the [file transfer docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/transfer/),

> Note: You will not see your documents using a file explorer on your device. 
>   Use adb:

```
adb shell 
run-as 
com.your.app 
cd files ls
```

cordova.file.dataDirectory saves in the app's private directory in root.
You can read the file in the app if required from entry object. [Check here for more](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)

If you want it to be publically accessible to the user, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076885/save-file-to-public-directory-using-cordova-filetransfer)

If you want progress you could use the `onProgress` listener in the api.

```
onProgress((event)=>{//do something})
```

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So basically - if I understand properly - the code is correct and the following question should be: How to move the files from the private folder to a public one?

Comment: And this by the way: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file should be the plugin I need?

Comment: no ionic-native file transfer uses that cordova plugin.

Comment: mmh.. then there is a way - using ionic-nativ file transfer - to move the file to a public directory and make it accessible to the user?

Comment: yes. use the same value for url as suggested by the stackoverflow link

Comment: Thanks Suraj. Just to be clear. In my code I should change cordova.file.dataDirectory with cordova.file.externalDataDirectory? That's correcT?

Comment: Thanks dude! I will check it now and then mark as correct!

Comment: I didn't manage to resolve the problem. Thanks anyway! I will probably make a more specific question about how to store it in a public location

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing `fileTransfer.download(url, cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'filename')`

**to:**

```
fileTransfer.download(url, cordova.file.externalRootDirectory +{{appName}} + 'filename')
```

See the WHERE TO STORAGE FILES in this link https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: what's `appName` here , can you please post the full code ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong in file transfer plugin need to install and need to create local access member in constructor is need to declare.

**First step1** Install plugin fileTransfer from framework docs.

**Second Step**

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

//import { Transfer } from 'ionic-native';

declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-documents',
  templateUrl: 'documents.html'
})

export class DocumentsPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File) {
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {

  }

  downloadFile()
  {
      const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
      let url = 'http://MY_URL.com/example.txt';

      fileTransfer.download(url, cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'example.txt').then((entry) => 
      {
          console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
      }, (error) => {
          // handle error
      });
  }
}
```

Now it will be bit meaning full for compile engine to understand