# cordova: download from url to android download folder

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Well before i start i tried below answers from stack overflow.

[Download file to downloads folder ios/android using phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375624/download-file-to-downloads-folder-ios-android-using-phonegap)

[FileTransfer Cordova download path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503051/filetransfer-cordova-download-path)

[Download a file to Downloads folder of device using Cordova FileTransfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220901/download-a-file-to-downloads-folder-of-device-using-cordova-filetransfer)

http://www.phonegaptutorial.com/downloading-an-image-from-the-internet-with-phonegap/

But no luck at all.

I am trying to download a file from internet.
My target is to download the file in download folder on Android phone.

I tried all the above answers and also i have used cordova example from cordova site.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.0.0/cordova/file/filetransfer/filetransfer.html

```
function downloadCL(){

var url = "http://www.phonegaptutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/phonegap-logo.png";

// we need to access LocalFileSystem
window.requestFileSystem(window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs)
{
     // create the download directory is doesn't exist
    fs.root.getDirectory('downloads', { create: true });

    // we will save file in .. downloads/phonegap-logo.png
    var filePath = fs.root.fullPath + '/downloads/' + url.split('/').pop();
    var fileTransfer = new window.FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(decodeURIComponent(url));

    fileTransfer.download(uri, filePath, function(entry)
    {
        alert("Successfully downloaded file, full path is " + entry.fullPath);
    },
  function(error)
    {
        console.log("Some error " + error.code + " for " + url +);
    }, 
    false);
}
                          };
};
```

Any advise how to achieve this.

Comment: why down vote? what is wrong with it?. At least comment the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fork,
you have to choose download file url,
local download file located here -
file:///storage/emulated/0/download
This link may help you -

[Cordova - Download a file in download folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575581/cordova-download-a-file-in-download-folder)

Added file transfer plugin to download such as -

https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/tree/master/asyncdownload

choose any as per requirement