# Cordova - Download a file in download folder

Tags: file, cordova, download

I've read a lot of posts but I got no the FINAL answer. 
Starting from the code at this [link](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/01/Cordova-Sample-Check-for-a-file-and-download-if-it-isnt-there), I got my file downloaded into the app. Anyway, I'd like to see it into the "Download" folder.
I'm using Android, but clearly I'd like a solution valid for iOS also.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT**

If you already know the path of the file you can just move it:

```js
var storageLocation = "";
console.log(device.platform);
switch (device.platform) {

    case "Android":
        storageLocation = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/';
        break;
    case "iOS":
        storageLocation = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
        break;

}


var fileUri = "file:///data/user/0/com.arsdigitalia.myapp/files/files/MyApp‌​/test.pdf"

function moveFile(fileUri) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
          fileUri,
          function(fileEntry){

                var parentEntry = storageLocation + "Download";
               
                // move the file to a new directory and rename it
               fileEntry.moveTo(parentEntry, "newFile.pdf", success, fail);
                       
          },
          errorCallback);
}
```

**Original**

Here is a sample piece of code I use to accomplish this. It works best on Android, iOS is a bit different due to the app sandboxing so you need to handle retrieving files yourself. I also use the Cordova device plugin to determine what device the app is running on, I can then change storage paths to suit:

```js
var storageLocation = "";
console.log(device.platform);
switch (device.platform) {

    case "Android":
        storageLocation = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/';
        break;
    case "iOS":
        storageLocation = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
        break;

}

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(storageLocation,
    function (fileSystem) {

        fileSystem.getDirectory('Download', {
                create: true,
                exclusive: false
            },
            function (directory) {

                //You need to put the name you would like to use for the file here.
                directory.getFile("YOUR_FILE_NAME", {
                        create: true,
                        exclusive: false
                    },
                    function (fileEntry) {


                        fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
                            writer.onwriteend = function () {
                                console.log("File written to downloads")
                            };

                            writer.seek(0);
                            writer.write(YOUR_FILE_HERE); //You need to put the file, blob or base64 representation here.

                        }, errorCallback);
                    }, errorCallback);
            }, errorCallback);
    }, errorCallback);

var errorCallback = function(e) {
    
    console.log("Error: " + e)
    
}
```

Then to retrieve the file list from the directory you can use:

```js
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(storageLocation,
    function (fileSystem) {
    
        fileSystem.getDirectory('Download', {
                create: true,
                exclusive: false
            },
            function (directory) {

                var reader = directory.createReader();
                reader.readEntries(function (files) {

                    if (files.length == 0) {

                        console.log("No files found in downloads folder.")

                    } else {

                        $.each(files, function (i, v) {

                            console.log("File Name: " + files[i].name;)

                        });

                    }

                }, getFilesFail);
            }, getFilesFail);
    }, getFilesFail);

var getFilesFail = function(e) {
    
    console.log("Error: " + e);
    
}
```

To install the device plugin use this command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

Documentation here:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/

Comment: for the line writer.write(YOUR_FILE_HERE); I think I can't use the filepath as YOUR_FILE_HERE. In fact I have: file:///data/user/0/com.arsdigitalia.myapp/files/files/MyApp/test.pdf but the original file of 400kB is not well copied (I found a file of 80B in the downloads folder). Suggestions?

Comment: Ok I used the readBinaryFile explained in the official plugin doc (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#download-a-binary-file-to-the-application-cache-) and I got the file. Just a final answer: I got access to the file using a file manager and seeing into the download folder, anyway, in the "official" download folder in Android 7.1 (the icon on the desk) I can't see it. Why?

Comment: I edited my post to include a function that should move a file from one directory to another. I think the reason you can't see it in the official download app is because it wasn't downloaded to that folder by the Android download manager.

Comment: Ok, but you should change your function to this one:

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
   fileUri,
   function (fileEntry) {
    var parentEntry = storageLocation + "Download";
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(parentEntry, function (store) {
     // move the file to a new directory and rename it
     fileEntry.moveTo(store, "newFile.pdf", function () {
      console.log("done moving");
     }, function () {
      console.log("error moving");
     });
    },errorCallback);
   },
   errorCallback);

Comment: Are you saying Downloads folder is in `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download` for Android

Comment: Does this still work?  I think for iOS you are moving a file to a `Download` folder inside the app directory path - which means the user still can't see it in their iPhones general `Downloads` folder.    Why has apple made this so hard.  You can download files to the users phone, but the user can't see them.

Answer (score 0):

Note for peoples who wants to see your downloaded files in iOS in iTunes and Files App: you have to enable both **UIFileSharingEnabled** and **LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace** in your info.plist